# Failed to compile because file not found in react JS

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand why react JS is giving me this error :

```
./src/index.js
Cannot find file: 'App.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: 
'.\src\app.js'.
```

I added the export/imports.

here is my App.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/login.component";

import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

here is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render((<App />), document.getElementById('root'));
```

here is the layout of my files.

[image: here is the layout of my files.]

thank you

Comment: Did you add the export for the `Login` component?

Comment: yes I did: export default Login; I will add the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename you file App.js to app.js

Comment: Already tried that, when i do i get this ```./src/index.js
Cannot find file: 'App.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\app.js'.```

Comment: after renaming try to save

Comment: I did it. and restarted the website aswell.

Comment: try this : npm install --save-dev case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin and restart